# Beamer: change default color of item's indicator in itemize

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

I'm using beamer with

```
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
```

and all the items' indicators in itemize (e.g., bullets, numbers, etc.) are blue (which is the main color of the dolphin theme).

What's the command to change the default color of the item's indicator? I want it to be of the same color of the text.

Comment: I think it's like another question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865581/changing-the-colour-of-textbullet-in-latex-beamer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865581/changing-the-colour-of-textbullet-in-latex-beamer

The best solution is:

```
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=color}
```

Another one but lower interest:

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color} % all frames will have red bullets

\begin{frame}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
    \item Fourth item.
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for reviving an old question, but I found it while looking for a similar solution. My problem however was that the bullet symbols should be always of the same color as the text, even though the text changes color depending on some environments.

I eventually tried to remove any specific coloring and it seems that

```
\setbeamercolor*{item}{}
```

works perfectly (all bullets are always of the current text color).